# mysql parent id loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I heve two Mysql tables

```
participants

id   |   name   | lastname |
-----------------------------
1    |    Jon   |   Bush   |
-----------------------------
2    |  Stephen |   Eagle  |
```

and

```
posts

id    |  parentid |  Title  |   text
--------------------------------------
1     |    1      |  Title1 |  Text1
---------------------------------------
2     |   1       | title3  |  text2
---------------------------------------
3     |      1    | title4  | text4
--------------------------------------
4     |      2    |   title |   ttext
```

And I need get out table

```
--------------------------
id (1) | Jon   | Title1, title3, title4
------------------------------
id (2) | Stephen | title
```

I try do this with

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, Title, participants.id, parent FROM aposts, participants WHERE paricipants.id = parent.parent group by last_name  ORDER BY .......");
```

But in this cas I cant get loop on parent to get out all posts of this parent... Maybe someone can help me....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want. Seeing your example, you want to return `Title` separated by comma for every `ID` and `Name`. MySQL has a builtin function called `GROUP_CONCAT` which concatenate rows instead of columns.

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.Name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.Title) TitleList
FROM    participants a
        INNER JOIN posts b
            ON a.ID = b.parentID
GROUP   BY  a.ID, a.Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/241cd/1)
- [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦═════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ ID ║  NAME   ║      TITLELIST       ║
╠════╬═════════╬══════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Jon     ║ Title1,title3,title4 ║
║  2 ║ Stephen ║ title                ║
╚════╩═════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

Comment: OK :) Thanks onemore time :)

Comment: One more question.. if I want add hyperlink to all of this "Title1,title3,title4" with it own id? So output must be something like this: <a href='index?id=Title1_id'>Title1</a>, <a href='index?id=itle3_id'>title3</a>......